# Windows 10 wake from sleep: possible on mouse button only, not mouse movement?

Tags: sleep

I have a Windows 10 box set to automatically sleep, but it will sometimes wake up when someone walks by.

Is there a way in Windows 10 keep waking up on a mouse button push, but not wake if the mouse is merely moved?

Bonus points for the same question for Linux or OSX.  In my case it's a standard wireless HID mouse.

I my case I know the mouse is set to wake (and testing it wakes both on movement and on button push):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
HID-compliant mouse (001)
HID Keyboard Device (003)
```